# Random blackscreen on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have my pc for five months now, running on windows version `20H2 (Build 19042.631)` and it always worked fine. I used it for gaming, coding and some schoolwork, but two days ago I experienced an issue with my graphics card as mentioned in the title.

This are my system specs if neccessary:
Core i7 10700KF
MSI RTX 2070 SUPER Ventus GP OC
1Tb Kingston NVME SSD
16Gb Viper Steel
MSI Z490-A Pro
Corsair RM 650X

1080p 144hz DisplayPort Monitor
900p 60hz HDMI Monitor

The blackscreen stayed for 3 seconds then I was able to use the pc for 7 seconds as usual until the process repeats. Later I was able to fix the problem temporary by starting a process that used the graphics card a lot for example a screen recorder or a game. But that stopped working after some time when windows crashed and reported a `VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE` with `nvlddmkm.sys`. When I tried to restart the system I got the error `CRITCAL_PROCESS_DIED` even in safe mode, so I made a backup of my data and reinstalled windows. It works much better now and I have updated to the latest driver version which is in my case `465.89`, but I am still experiencing random blackscreens which hold on for about 3 seconds.Those blackscreens occur when the display changes a lot, eg when I maximize a youtube window. Hopefully someone has experienced the same issue or is able to help me.

Thank you

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a hardware failure.

Comment: I think you are right, because my whole system stopped woeking now and I am not even getting a picture anymore. Thanks